# android wear notification with different text styles

Tags: android, wear-os, text-styling, android-wear-notification

On [Add a Big View](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html#BigView) Google show how to make use of BigTextStyle. The screenshot looks very promising:

[image]

- So I can see a title "Emmet Connolly" which I can set with setContentTitle().
- And I can see a bold header "Re: wearables" which I don't know how to set.
- Finally there is some text "Our devs are goint to be building a lot of really awesome apps" which should be set with setContentText().

I played around with some setters from NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle and I can summarize that some are ignored. Seems to be a bug ?!

```
final NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
        .setBackground(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.chalk));

final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("text") // overwritten by bigText()
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText("big text")
                .setBigContentTitle("big content title") // ignored
                .setSummaryText("summary text")) // ignored
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
        .extend(wearableExtender);

final NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
manager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out?

Answer (score 2):

Html seems to work:

```
.setContentText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Best</b> restaurant <i>in</i> <font color=\"#0000ff\">San</font> Francisco <a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\">#food"))
```

An here is a useful link: [HTML Tags Supported By TextView](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)